# What is the 'Accuracy' of Markov's inequality upper bound estimate

Tags: probability, self-study, stochastic-processes

[image]

I'm confused with part e) in this question since nowhere at all in my notes was 'accuracy' of the upper bound brought up.

What I calculated for c) was:

P(N3>0)=0.422 for p=0

P(N3>0)=0.2929 for p=1/8

P(N3>0)=0.210 for p=1/4

And the upper bound for all p in part d was : 0.422

What should I be looking out for here? My uninformed instinct is to say that p=0 has the most accurate upper bound estimate since it's the closest however it may be a trick question and has the same accuracy for any value of p.

Comment: Can't even find any mention of the accuracy of markovs inequality online...

Answer (score 0):

The "accuracy" of the estimate is not really some special technical term; it seems like it's just referring to how close the estimate is to the actual value. Your first instinct was right.